# Why is OTs a good leaving group and how does it work?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've been told that $\ce{OTs}$ is a good leaving group for substitution reactions, but I'm not sure how it works or why it is a good leaving group. Can someone please explain?

$\ce{Ts}$ comes from Toluenesulfonyl chloride, and when the $\ce{Ts-}$ ion replaces and H in an alcohol, it becomes an $\ce{OTs}$ group.

Answer (score 6):

Tosylate groups ($\ce{CH3C6H4SO3-}$) are good leaving groups because their conjugate base forms are quite stabilized by resonance:

[image]